# How to create a forestplot in meta analysis of correlation (error message about xlim)?

Tags: r, plot, correlation, analysis

I'm a beginner in R and I'm trying to run a meta-analysis of correlations, but when I try to plot the data in a plot I get an error.
I am learning the code from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1pYHfCKhyA
I would really appreciate any help or advise you can give me.
This is my code:

```
install.packages("metafor")
install.packages("robumeta")
install.packages("dplyr")

library(metafor)
library(robumeta)
library(dplyr)

Main<- read.csv("Meta-main.csv")
Main <- mutate(Main, study_id = 1:23)
Main <- Main %>% select(study_id, Authur:Quality)
View(Main)


Main <-escalc(measure = "ZCOR", ri=EffSize, ni=Ssize, data = Main, slab = paste(Authur, Year, sep = ", "))
View(Main)

res <- rma(yi, vi, data = Main)
res
predict(res, digits = 3, transf = transf.ztor)
confint(res)

b_res <- rma(yi, vi, data = Main, slab = study_id)
baujat(b_res)

inf<-influence(res)
print(inf)
plot(inf)

forest(res, xlim=c(-1.6,1.6), atransf = transf.ztor,
       at = transf.rtoz(c(-4,-2,0,.2,.4,.6)), digits = c(2,1),cex = .8)
```

This is the error:

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

I tried to solve it myself by x<-1.6:1.6 but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `at=transf.rtoz(c(-4,-2,0,.2,.4,.6))` yields `-Inf` and `Inf` values. I think you meant to use `at=transf.rtoz(c(-.4,-.2,0,.2,.4,.6))` and then it should work.